# Small problem in my JS slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have problem in my slideshow .

First see the: [example + code](http://jsfiddle.net/lionking/CyCDD/11) 
The problem in the image top margin shows part of the previous picture and is repeated every time .
please help me to solve this problem , what's the wrong in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your images have some space between them.  If you look at my original version of that here: http://jsfiddle.net/lionking/CyCDD/, you will see that I set font-size: 0 in the CSS to make sure there was no space between the images.

You will also need to force the width of your slideshow container to make sure that there is only one slide per row.  In your example if you make the window wider, you get two or more slides per row.

Comment: You are very good man . thank you for All your Help . you are worthy of evaluation